# What's good way to add items to workflow on child publication?

Tags: 2013-sp1, workflow

I'm implementing following workflow.

1. Editor creates components and pages, and publish them to staging site.
2. Add thoes components and pages to a bundle.
3. Start workflow by the bundle.
4. Reviewer review contents by seeing pages in the bundle on staging site.
5. Reviewer approve pages and publish them to live site by XPM.

On parent publiation in Blueprint, it's no problem.

But on child publication, user cannot add page which is not localized to workflow.
So on child publication, only localized components are sent to reviewer by workflow.

Reasons why I want to add pages to workflow are following.

Let reviewer know which pages he should see on staging site and publish.
If there are no page in bundle, reviewer cannot know which page he should see.
It's straightforward that editor adds pages reviewer should see to bundle.

I think there are some workarounds, but user's operation should be simple as possible, 
so complicated workarounds are not good.

I want to know how Tridion user operate workflow on actual Tridion enviroment.

Does anyone know it?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I believe the default behavior is correct and make sense as well. 
We do create workflow to apply approval process before content/page published to live. So if master page is already in workflow and if you have defined the **minimum approval status** on master page that it wouldn't allow child page to be published as well until it reach to **Minimum approval status**.
I understand you want to validate the child page as well during approval cycle. I would suggest you to implement custom email notification which will send the master and child page urls for different language editors to validate and they can also add their localized component in bundle if not there and make required changes.

Hope it make sense.

Comment: Using the Tridion API you can retrieve the URL of the parent item and also the child page.  You definitely need some custom programming to make this work.  One idea is you can have a metadata field int he Bundle and store the Page URL there for those items, and then easily access it later on.  Setting the URL in the bundle will be a challenge.  Otherwise, I like the idea to send the user an email with the Page URL.  And, I agree with you this would be the best way for the user.